# RDF/XML Jena getValue

Tags: java, xml, rdf, jena

i need a help for getting some information out of the RDF with Jena Framework.
I have an RDF content like this:

```
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:ts="http://www.test.com/testModel.owl#">  
<ts:Entity rdf:ID="1234_test"> 
 <....>
</ts>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Now my idea is to get out the ID from ts:Entity. This is my code:

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
InputStream requestBody = new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes());
String BASE = "http://www.test.com/testModel.owl#";
model.read(requestBody,BASE);
requestBody.close();

StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();
 while (iter.hasNext()) {

        Statement stmt      = iter.nextStatement();  // get next statement
        Resource  subject   = stmt.getSubject();     // get the subject
        Property  predicate = stmt.getPredicate();   // get the predicate
        RDFNode   object    = stmt.getObject();      // get the object

            System.out.println(subject + " | "+predicate);

     }
```

The only problem, in that case, is that i have to scroll all the Statement. There is a way for getting direct the  ID from ts:Entity ? Maybe before getting the resource and after the value of the ID related to that resource.

Thanks in advance for helping.

---

Sorry, i am again here, because i have a similar question, if for example i have this rdf:

```
<rdf:RDF
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:ts="http://www.test.com/testModel.owl#">  
<ts:Entity rdf:ID="1234_test"> 
   <ts:Resource> 
       <ts:testProp rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">test_ID_test</ts:testProp>
 </ts>
</ts>
</rdf:RDF>
```

How i can extract the value test_ID_test??? And if i want use SPARQL how can i do with jena???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Resource ENTITY_TYPE = model.getResource("http://www.test.com/testModel.owl#Entity");
StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements(null, RDF.type, ENTITY_TYPE);
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String entityID = iter.next().getSubject().getURI();
    System.out.println(entityID);
}
```

That will get the URI of each entity.

Comment: Thank you so much...The only error is: String entityID = iter.nextStatement().getSubject().getURI(); because you need a statement for getting the Subject.

Comment: I leave further improvements as an exercise for the questioner :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should be using [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) to query your model rather than iterating over all the statements.  Jena provides a good [tutorial](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql.html) on how to use SPARQL with their API.

Comment: I think I would say that you *could* also use SPARQL to query your model. In my code, I use SPARQL about 50% of the time, the rest of the time I use the model (or OntModel) API directly. It all depends what makes the code clearest. It is often true that using a SPARQL query approach doesn't increase in complexity as quickly as the API if the RDF property chain you want to explore gets longer. On the other hand, disjunctions can be clearer in API calls than in SPARQL queries.

Comment: Thanks, maybe could be another approach!

Comment: sorry can you give me an example how to make the SPARQL query for extracting the rdf:ID??